# Catalyst equivalent for Rails script console

Tags: perl, console, read-eval-print-loop, catalyst, rails-console

Is there anything like Ruby on Rails' script console for Perl's Catalyst? From [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html):

> The console command lets you interact with your Rails application from the command line. On the underside, rails console uses IRB, so if you’ve ever used it, you’ll be right at home. This is useful for testing out quick ideas with code and changing data server-side without touching the website.

I found a [blog post](http://www.solarant.org/blog/shell-for-catalyst/) talking about implementing it with Devel::REPL, but I cannot get it to work...

Comment: Buy not describing the console, you've limited yourself to be helped by only those that know both Rails and Catalyst.

Comment: Don't forget that using `script/myapp_server -r` causes the server to restart itself if any of the modules files in your project change. Useful when debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And, for that matter only a **very** small percentage of Perl users use opt for the Perl debugger at all -- this is largely because it's faster to execute and throw an exception, and because of the total transparency of Perl Objects -- they're just blessed Hashes and they serialize into strings pretty well.

I happen to like [XXX](https://metacpan.org/module/XXX), drop an

```
use XXX;
XXX \%hash;
```

or do a `Catalyst::Exception->throw( YYY %v );`

Comment: I don't use perl -d, but I use Devel::REPL a lot -- mainly to try out some small pieces of code which are not working or which I'm not sure are going to work.


I have a limited experience with RoR's console, but I really like that it allows you to actually do stuff (adding/removing data from the DB, etc), instead of only allowing you to inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [CatalystX::REPL](https://metacpan.org/module/CatalystX%3a%3aREPL) with success. I'm not familiar with the RoR console but, basically, CatalystX::REPL will drop you into an interactive environment where you can inspect the application's context object and so on.

Comment: Yeah CatalystX::REPL is great, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I think it only goes to the interactive environment when you reach an error or exception.

Comment: That is correct. Though, thinking about it, there must be a way to start it directly...?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but I don't know if it is possible, I have never seen anyone doing something like that with CatalystX::REPL!